# C# parallel programming with list - is reading thread-safe?

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing

I'm reading a book about parallel programming an it says that it's not thread save to add elements to list without using lock as result will be unpredictable. For example if we have to add 800 000 elements to list, final result will have less then 800 000 elements.

Now I am wondering if it is thread save to **read** elements from the list. For example lets say that I have a list `BlackListedNumbers`

```
List<int> BlackListedNumbers = new List<int> {10, 50 ....... n}; 
//lets say there is 500 000 elements in the list
```

and another list `Numbers` containing 10 000 000 numbers, obviously I'll use  parallel.Foreach to complete this task and what I want is `Final` list containing all numbers from `Numbers` that are not in `BlackListedNumbers` list

```
List<int> finalList = new List<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(Numbrs, 
  num =>
    {
      if (!blackListedNumbrs.Contains(num))
      {
        lock (finalList)
        {
          finalList.Add(num);
        }
      }
  });
```

I know that this is not the most efficient way to get this done but I'm just trying to illustrate the problem.

So my question is: Is it thread save to read result from List `blackListedNumbrs` and will I get 100% accurate results?

Comment: For List<T>, that is safe. However, it is not *in general* safe to read from a data structure on multiple threads, even an allegedly "immutable" structure. The collection still has to be designed to support safe multithreading. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/23/read-only-and-threadsafe-are-different.aspx for some more thoughts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

> A `List<T>` can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified.

So if you never modify the list, you should be fine.

Note that using a `HashSet<int>` would be rather more efficient - and `HashSet<T>` also supports multiple readers<sup>1</sup>. You can *also* use Parallel LINQ to make your query sweeter and almost certainly more efficient:

```
// If you want duplicates in Numbers to still come up as duplicates in the result
HashSet<int> blacklistedSet = new HashSet<int>(blackListedNumbers);
List<int> finalList = Numbers.AsParallel()
                             .Where(x => !blacklistedSet.Contains(x))
                             .ToList();

// Or if you just want a set-based operation:

List<int> finalList = Numbers.AsParallel()
                             .Except(blacklistedSet)
                             .ToList();
```

Much nicer, and no locking required :)

---

<sup>1</sup> As noted in comments, I don't have any documentation to back this up. But reading from a set doesn't need to modify any shared state, so it at least makes *sense*...

Comment: @Jon, my understanding is that it is safe to concurrently read from the list using the indexer (`list[i]`), but looping (`foreach`) won't be safe as it uses an enumerator. Is this correct or is it also safe to foreach over a list from multiple threads (assuming of course it is never written to)?

Comment: @Darin: If nothing is modifying the list, I believe it's absolutely fine to iterate over it. It's not like the list iterator needs to make any modifications. The MSDN documentation says it's unsafe, but if you read on it talks about that occurring in the presence of other writes. Bear in mind that each call to `GetEnumerator()` will return a *separate* iterator.

Comment: @Darin: It is safe to read from one list using two enumerators, one on each thread. It is not safe to read from one list using one enumerator, with calls to MoveNext on the enumerator on different threads. The *list* is threadsafe for multiple readers, but moving an enumerator forward *writes to the enumerator*, and that's not safe.

Comment: @Darin: Sorry, yes - I should have been clearer about what I meant. It's rare to want to iterate using a single iterator on many threads... although I've blogged about it: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/10/23/iterating-atomically.aspx

Comment: Jon, Eric, it's like heaven on Earth. Your knowledge is priceless for the community. Now a couple of locks are awaiting removal from my code :-) *sigh.

Comment: @Jon: What benefit does using `HashSet<T>` provide in this example? Won't the `Except` just treat it as a standard sequence, the same as it would with `List<T>` too?

Comment: @LukeH: Actually, I need to make a change here - as this will give a unique sequence (a set) instead of the original version. Will edit. Basically using `Contains` is obviously quick on a `HashSet<T>`, which is what I originally thought of - then it reminded me of Except :)

Comment: @JonSkeet "HashSet<T> also supports multiple readers" do you have a source for this? (Like for the list)

Comment: @Magnus: I don't, actually. I'm pretty sure it *does*, but I don't have anything to back that up...

Answer (score 1):

As long as noone else is writing/adding/deleting `blackListedNumbers` yes

Answer (score 0):

Read is safe so your code above should work fine, and indeed adding records to the list with multiple threads will cause problems.  .NET 4.0 introduced [Thread-Safe Colections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) In your case you can use [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) to use multiple threads to add items to the collection.

Here is my example of using it:

```
var data = new ConcurrentBag<DJVSStatsEv>();

Parallel.ForEach(globalData.ValuationEventsPit, item =>
              {
                   data.Add(new DJVSStatsEv(item.DateYearMonth, item.EventType, eventGroup) {PostVal = item.PostVal, PreVal = item.PreVal, Raised = item.Raised});
             });
```